# How to save query results to a new sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I want to save the results of my `sqlite` query in a new `sqlite` file. in other words, I want to have a new `sqlite` database with the data which resulted from my query on my previous data set.

All I have found on the internet was how to export the query results to csv or sql. but I want my new data set to be `sqlite`.

Also, is there any way to save the query results on the same data set (like what we do in excel)? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can [ATTACH](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) another database file to an existing connection and create or insert data into a table in that other database.

Something like:

```
ATTACH DATABASE 'other.db' AS other;
CREATE TABLE other.foo AS SELECT * FROM main.foo; -- create and populate a table
INSERT INTO other.bar SELECT * FROM main.foo; -- insert into an existing table
DETACH other;
```

Comment: the error says:  ```Result: unable to open database: other.db
At line 1:
ATTACH DATABASE 'other.db' AS other;``` I am very new to this. maybe there are some steps you assume I know and skipped?

Comment: @Pie-ton Do you have permission to create files in whatever your current working directory is?